# Put element p value inside input text field

Tags: php, html, input, bootstrap-modal

I am facing small issues while trying to move value p inside input text field. 
This is my value p :

```
<p id="venue"></p>
```

and now how to insert this p value inside the input text field?

```
<input class="form-control" type="textarea" placeholder="Venue/Facility" size="1"/>
```

thanks,
faizal

Comment: You can't insert the `<p>` tag element inside input. But you can inside `<div>` element

Comment: Why do you want to to that?

Comment: value of <p> inside input ? or whole <p> tag inside input ?

Comment: I continue other people work, so I do not know how to explain about this. Plus I am new with this. 
@aldrin27 can you show a simple code by using div.? 

faizal,

Comment: What do you want to be the expected output?

Comment: the flow is, first user will click the button, this button from different table. then button will pass value text to another table which is inside of the input text field. so here, the value text can be passed by using <p>, but the problem is the value not inside the input text field.

Comment: @Dong You can try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example is like;

```
<p id="venue">THIS IS P ELEMENT</p> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="texted"/>
```

JS Code

```
var text = $('#venue').html();
$('#texted').val(text);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkhns895/1/)

With button click function

HTML

```
<p id="venue">THIS IS P ELEMENT</p>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="texted" />
<button type="button" id="btn">copy me</button>
```

JS

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var text = $('#venue').html();
    $('#texted').val(text);
});
```

[Button click function](http://jsfiddle.net/tkhns895/2/)

Sidenote: the input type is wrong, it should be `text` not `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<p id="venue">THE VALUE</p> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="field"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var p = $('#venue').html();
  $('#field').val(p);
});
```